# How to easily paint an unwrapped uv map?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, texture-painting

So say for example I have this UV map from a car I want to paint.
[image: Example UV Map]

Is there any easy way to add images on top of it? I mean, the lateral of the car is divided in multiple parts and I can't find a way to place images on top of it other than cutting the image as many times as I need following the path of each part, which is hard as f*** and also not very precise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can export the UV layout and work with an image editor app like Photoshop or Krita

Comment: I would generally recommend do this in some image editing software instead of Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use two tecniques:

- 1
  Paint directly onto the 3D model using Blender texture paint tools, maybe applying textures as decals.
- 2
  Create a second UV Map (UV Map Painter in my example), suitable for painting; export its UV Layout; execute the texturing work in your preferred image editor software, and then bake the texture on a new image using the old UV Map (UV Map Original in my example).

[image]